# Data not saving for discord.py bot on github

Tags: python, json, github, heroku, discord.py

I made a discord bot and hosted it on Heroku using Github. A part of the bot is a leveling system that saves the information to a folder called users.json. Since I have switched over from local hosting to hosting it on Heroku it is not saving. My code is bellow:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await client.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1


async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp


async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('levels.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end

@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'You are at level {lvl}!')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is at level {lvl}!')
```

Comment: If you host via Heroku, nothing is updated on Github to my knowledge. I believe that this is generally not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku hosts static apps only, it means you can not modify files there.

Comment: oh okay thank you, but is there any other way that i can get to update it? like a different way to host the bot?

Comment: I think you should use python dictionary instead of json file, that data can be modified.,, but it will reset when you restart app.

Answer (score 1):

Hosting the Discord Bot on Heroku is still the best option, but considering the [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) you need to use an external storage to persist your data.

Assuming you still want to store files (ie not converting the app to use a DB) you have various options:

- Amazon S3 (using Python boto3 module)
- Dropbox
- GitHub itself (save users.json with the source code)

See [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) to understand the details of each option.

Comment: Thanks this should help me with my problem

Comment: I'm having some problems with the github way the explanation on the website you sent me is not explaining what you need to do very well. Itkind of rushes over somethings if you can't help I completely understand.

Comment: Did you look at the GitHub repository as well? There is a Python example on how to create or update a file. Each file change is a commit. Basically you store the json file with the source code. Maybe it is not ideal but it is pretty straight-forward

Comment: Link to example: https://github.com/gcatanese/HerokuFiles/blob/main/app/github_api.py

Comment: At this point i just think I'm stupid ugh :faceplam: Idon't understand at all lol ill figure it out though