# Committing a file to github upon it updating

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.py

Pretty much I run a discord bot through Heroku and I have a leaderboard.csv file that updated with player names and scores, but I noticed that when I edit the file through the discord bot (using Heroku), the changes do not update the file in GitHub. So if I have to update my code the leaderboard is reset to whatever is on the GitHub. Any way I can change this? I deploy using GitHub but if there is a way to fix this by changing deploy methods I will do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401254/data-not-saving-for-discord-py-bot-on-github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data not saving for discord.py bot on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401254/data-not-saving-for-discord-py-bot-on-github)

Comment: Why are you using github as a database? Don't do that, use a proper database like postgresql.